# JBoss Netty getting User IP (Http Request)

Tags: ip, netty

I need to log the user ip ady's for every request to our JBoss Netty server. I thought:

```
MessageEvent e;
e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress();
```

was the correct answer, but this always returns 127.0.0.1 and I need the actual client ip. Coming from Rails I checked how they find out the ip, from the docu:

> Determines originating IP address.
>   REMOTE_ADDR is the standard but will
>   fail if the user is behind a proxy.
>   HTTP_CLIENT_IP and/or
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR are set by
>   proxies so check for these if
>   REMOTE_ADDR is a proxy.
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR may be a comma-
>   delimited list in the case of multiple
>   chained proxies; the last address
>   which is not trusted is the
>   originating IP.

So should I check for all the headers in Netty or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have the answer. Using ChannelHandlerContext instead of MessageEvent does the trick.

```
SocketAddress remoteAddress = ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress();
```